# VueJS - Module not found

Tags: vue.js

I'm having a very hard time importing CSS files in a Vue component. Basically I have the following component:

```
<template>
    <html>
        <body>
        ...
        </body>
    </html>
</template>
```

Now I need to import CSS and JavaScript files that are needed for this template, so I tried this:

```
<template>
    <html>
        <body>
        ...
        </body>
    </html>
</template>

<style>

@import './assets/css/bootstrap.min'
@import './assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min'
@import './assets/css/style.css'

</style>
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError in 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/css/bootstrap.min'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is how the folder is structured:

```
-assets
-component.vue
```

Comment: you need `.css` at the end, also you dont need `<html><body></body></html>` in components

Comment: Try importing them outside of the style tags with require or JS `import`